# Are IP tables persisted in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I ran some iptables commands to forward a port, but it is unclear if these will be persisted with reboots. I have not installed any additional packages, and it is a standard ubuntu 14.04 install, so the default behavior should hold true.

It would be a bit of a pain to rebuild the server to test this (rebooting during operational hours is not an option) so I thought I'd ask here. Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

No, iptables only affect the current, running kernel. To store the running config use `iptables-save`, and `iptables-restore` to reload your setup, usually at boot.
For instance do as follow:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf
```

And add this to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
iptables-restore /etc/iptables.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iptables-persistent package for that.

```
$ sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

Make chances as desired to the iptables configuration and save them with the following command:

```
$ sudo invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save
```